# como faço para inserir variáveis de uma query select em um bancos de um servidor diferente?

Tags: php, mysql

Gostaria de fazer uma conexão em `php` em dois bancos de dados só que estão em redes distintas, nessa conexão precisaria fazer uma busca em um banco em um servidor e inserir numa tabela em um banco em outro servidor

por exemplo:

```
$conecta = mysql_connect("rede1","usuario","senha");
$db = mysql_select_db("banco1");
```

e colocar uma segunda conexão :

```
$conecta1 = mysql_connect("rede2","usuario","senha");
$db = mysql_select_db("banco2");
```

//aqui é onde eu faço a query para buscar os dados que vai ser armazenados nas variáveis

```
$serial = $_POST['serial'];

$query = mysqli_query("select coluna1 coluna2... from tabela1 where coluna 1 = '$serial'");

$result = mysqli_fecth_array($query);

$qry = $result['coluna2'];
```

por exemplo:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conecta,"select * from tabela1");
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
```

e com resultado dessa query faz um insert em uma tabela no banco no outro servidor

```
$insert = mysqli_query(conecta1."insert into tabela2 values ('resultado da query acima')");
```

eu sei que dá pra fazer o insert com o select dentro
por exemplo:

```
$insert = mysqli_query($conecta1."insert into tabela2(".."select '$qry'... from tabela1) on duplicate key update coluna2 = values(coluna2)...");
```

eu preciso preencher uma tabela de banco de um servidor tal e esse preenchimento vai ser o vindo de uma query select, onde os dados vai ser armazenados em uma variável vinda de um primeira query select

Fiz dessa maneira mas não deu certo, alguém sabe se existe em `php` uma maneira de fazer isso ? desde então agradeço.

Comment: Isso é uma questão de rede e não de PHP.

Comment: Não poderia usar um BD por vez?

Answer (score 1):

Nessa altura do compeonato você não deveria estar usando mysql_*, foi depreciado, php7 já não funciona mais,
você deveria estar usando pdo, mysqli_ ou algum framework.

Mas se você insiste em usar mysql_

```
$conecta1 = mysql_connect("rede1","usuario1","senha1");
mysql_select_db("banco1", $conecta1);

$conecta2 = mysql_connect("rede2","usuario2","senha2");
mysql_select_db("banco2", $conecta2);

mysql_query('select * from tablenamebanco1', $conecta1);
mysql_query('select * from tablenamebanco2', $conecta2);
```

Se você não passar o identificador no final a ultima conexão criada será usada.